# a proof idea: Every well-ordered set has an order-preserving bijection to exactly one ordinal.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

I have seen a proof of the statement, and its usually by transfinite induction. And I'm trying to find out why my proof doesn't work, it seems too simple:

Let $X$ be a well-ordered set. Define $X^{<x} = \{w \in X: w < x\}$ for all $x \in X$. Now define also $Z = \{X^{<x} : x \in X\}$. It is clear that $Z$ is an ordinal and there's a bijection that preserves order between $X$ and $Z$, namely $x \mapsto X^{<x}$.

This bijection is furthermore unique because we know that two ordinals admit an order-preserving bijection between them if and only if they
are identical, and in that case the only order-preserving bijection is the identity map.

__

Any feedback would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "It is clear that $Z$ is an ordinal." Is it clear? How do you define ordinals? Because the way I define them they are some very specific sets, and I don't see why your construction would yield *those* sets.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm using the following definition: A set $S$ is an ordinal if and only if $S$ is strictly well-ordered with respect to set membership and every element $s$ of $S$ is the set of its predecessors in $S$. Does it not follow directly from the definition that $Z$ should be an ordinal?

Comment: No. Take $X=\{x,y\}$ with $x\lt y$, with $x$ not the empty set. Then $X^{\lt x}=\varnothing$, $X^{\lt y}=\{x\}$, so $Z=\{\varnothing,\{x\}\}$. This is not well ordered with respect to set membership: we have $\varnothing\notin\{x\}$, and $x\notin \varnothing$. So it is not only not clear, it is not even true.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the answer, and I'm very sorry I did a typo, $S$ should be strictly well-ordered with respect to *set inclusion* and not set membership. So in this case we have $\varnothing \subset \{x\}$

Comment: Still not necessarily an ordinal under your definition, now because the second clause of your definition need not be met.  In $Z$ ordered by inclusion, the set of predecessors of $\{x\}$ is $\{\varnothing\}$. But $\{x\}\neq \{\varnothing\}$, so it is not true that each element in $Z$ is the set of its predecessors.

Comment: (What you did was not a "typo", it was an *error*. Don't minimize it, own up to it...)

Comment: I think the only time your $Z$ is an ordinal is if $X$ was an ordinal to begin with.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin (Yes it was indeed an error, it was my mistake, I thought that was the definition of typo, sorry I offended you)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the explanation. Are we allowed to simply write (abuse of notation) $x = \varnothing$ and $y = \{x\}$? So we assume equality instead of bijection. Because in this case, the set of predecessors of $x$ is simply the empty set, and the set of predecessors of $y$ is $\{x\}$, so $Z$ fulfills the definition of ordinal?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I was referring to [2.0.4] https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/14.pdf

Comment: No, you aren't allowed to do that. Assuming you can do that is equivalent to assuming you can biject $X$ with an ordinal.  The way you define ordinals requires **equality**, not bijections.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see, I understand now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be on the right track, but with some current errors as pointed out in the comments. The idea of looking at $X^{<x}$ is good, but $Z$ is not necessarily an ordinal as it is currently defined.

For ease of speaking about it, it may help to give the desired order-preserving bijection a name, such as $\pi$. The goal is to have $X$ be the domain of $\pi$, and some ordinal be the range. For $x\in X$, define $\pi(x)=\{\pi(y)\mid y<x\}$, you may also think of this as the image of $X^{<x}$ under $\pi$ if you like to think in terms of $X^{<x}$. Then, $\pi$ has to have an ordinal as its range, i.e. the range of $\pi$ is transitive and well-ordered by $\in$ (linearly ordered by $\in$ and $\in$ is well-founded on $X$).

The following comes straight from the definition of $\pi$ and will be very useful:

$$\begin{align}\textrm{For }x,y\in X\textrm{, }x<y\iff\pi(x)\in\pi(y)\end{align}$$

The relation $<$ is transitive, so for any $x,y,z\in X$, $\pi(x)\in\pi(y)$ and $\pi(y)\in\pi(z)$ implies $\pi(x)\in\pi(z)$, so $\in$ is transitive on the range of $\pi$. Since $<$ is a linear ordering, $\in$ is a linear ordering on $X$. Finally, $\in$ must be well-founded on $X$ because any infinite decreasing $\ldots\in\pi(x_2)\in\pi(x_1)\in\pi(x_0)$ would correspond to an infinite decreasing chain $\ldots<x_2<x_1<x_0$ in $X$, which contradicts well-orderednss of $<$. (A shorter argument relying on the axiom of foundation is that $\in$ must be well-founded on $X$ directly from the axiom.)